# PHPのカレンダー1日から始まる月の表示が崩れる問題を解決したいです。

Tags: php, html

恐らくtbodyの中のどこかがおかしいと思われるのですが、
どこが原因が知りたいです。よろしくお願いします。
windows10 pro64 1903 PHP7.3.8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>PHPカレンダー</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <?php
  $year = 0; //表示する年
  $month = 0; //表示する月
  $dow = ['日', '月', '火', '水', '木', '金', '土'];
  if (isset($_GET['y'])) {
    $year = intval($_GET['y']);
  }
  if (isset($_GET['m'])) {
    $month = intval($_GET['m']);
  }
  if (!$year || !$month || !checkdate($month, 1, $year)) {
    //現在の年月
    $now_date = new DateTime();
    $year = $now_date->format('Y');
    $month = $now_date->format('m');
  }

  try {
    $datetime = new DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-1"); //表示する月（例外処理）
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
  }

  $first_day = $datetime->format('w'); //1日の曜日
  ?>
</head>

<body>
  <?php echo $datetime->format('Y年m月'); ?>

  <table>
    <caption><?php $datetime->format('Y年m月'); ?></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($dow as $day) : ?>
          <th><?php echo $day ?></th>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($date = 1; $date <= $datetime->format('t'); $date++) { ?>
          <?php
          if ($date === 1) {
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $first_day) {
          ?>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <?php
              $i++;
            }
          }
          ?>
          <td><?php echo $date ?></td>
          <?php if ($date % 7 === 7 - $first_day) { ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <?php
    $datetime->modify('-1 month');
    ?>
    <a href="calen.php?y=<?php echo $datetime->format('Y') ?>&m=<?php echo $datetime->format('m') ?>">前月</a>
    <?php
    $datetime->modify('+2 months');
    ?>
    <a href="calen.php?y=<?php echo $datetime->format('Y') ?>&m=<?php echo $datetime->format('m') ?>">翌月</a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは、はじめまして。
62行目、7-$first_dayの**剰余**で**trタグ**を閉じて改行する位置を求めてるのですが、$first_dayが0の場合はこの条件が成立しなくなります。**三項演算子**で解決すると下記のようになります。
(もしあなたがはじめたばかりの方ならどうか、強調した部分でわからない単語をしらべてください:->)

```
<?php if ($first_day==0?$date%7===0:$date % 7 === 7 - $first_day) { ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました。$first_day = $datetime->format('w')をしていたので、日曜日は１になり、$first_dayは０にはならないと考えていましたが違うのですか？可能であればご教授お願いします。

Comment: 仕様では0-6になるようです。疑問に感じたとき公式ドキュメントは役に立ちますよ。https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.date.php

Comment: わがまままで聞いてもらって、本当に勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: いえいえどういたしまして。よろしければ、課題を解決としていただけると嬉しいです。